# How to setup nmap ping count?

Tags: nmap

I need an arp-ping tool for windows
Tried arp-ping http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/arp-ping.php.
Source address specification did not work in this tool.
Then I came across nmap. -PR option suits my needs and it works.

My arp ping example command

nmap -sn -PR 192.169.0.1 -S 192.168.0.100

I would like to know how to make this scan, ping infinitely. More like a '-t' switch in windows ping tool

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. From what you are describing what you want is nping (part of the Nmap project).

This will let you send arp pings and allow you to send continuous pings.

You can download nping from the Nmap download page.

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I needed. Still trying to figure out a way to send continuous pings. There is a '-c' switch to specify count. But could not find out a way to ping until stopped

Comment: Try the switch --r

Comment: Well --r switch did not work. But specifying count as 0 made it work. :)

Comment: Sorry, that was the one I was thinking about. :) I'm glad it works!